# How can I update a specific users rank after paypal purchase? (IPN)

Tags: php, sql, paypal, paypal-ipn

I want to update a logged in users rank after they purchase the upgrade automatically.
Below is an example that I can't get to work.

```
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);


    if($result == "VERIFIED")
       {

               session_start();
               $db_host="localhost";
               $db_name="mydb";
               $username="user";
               $password="psw";
               $conn = mysql_connect($db_host, $username, $password);
               $connection_string=mysql_select_db($db_name);
               $sql  = "UPDATE users SET rank ='10' WHERE username                  ='{$_SESSION['username']}'";
               $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );

       }
    else
       {

       }
```

I'm aware (IPN) creates a new session are there any ways to work around this?

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: What error are you getting? There is a typo in your `$sql` string. It needs to be closed and needs some more information, like `$sql = "UPDATE users SET rank = '10' WHERE username='great username'"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the `$_SESSION['username']` to the custom field of your payment button, -

```
custom='{$_SESSION['username']}'
```

Then in your IPN you can get value back-

```
$username = $_POST['custom'];
```

and use that in your sql update -

```
$sql  = "UPDATE users SET rank ='10' WHERE username ='$username'";
```

https://cms.paypal.com/es/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables#id08A6HH00W2J